# How to check if argument is varArgs

Tags: java, android, logging

I wrap the android Log class in my own as

```
public static void d(String tag, String msg, long... varArgs) {
    Log.d(tag, String.format(msg, varArgs));
}
```

But if the argument I pass in is not a varArgs I get a warning. But worse, the value is printed weird. Like if I call `myLog.d(TAG,"timestamp %s",timestamp)`, then I get `timestamp: [J@3d4e5d16`

Gradle compile warning:

> warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type
>   for last parameter;
>           Log.d(tag, String.format(msg, varArgs));

Comment: First of all, you are using `%s` to print a integral value.

Comment: Second of all, please give a specific example that generates a warning and the **exact** warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you are not sending var args, but that you are sending a `long[]` which is the first element of a variable number of `Object` arguments.

This fixes your issue:

```
Log.d(tag, String.format(msg, (Object[]) varArgs))
```

Comment: I see the problem. Instead of `long... varArgs` I should have had `Object... varArgs`. Now it works with my fix.

Comment: That would work too, it seemed you wanted for some reason for `d` to take a `long...`, though I could not figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

No decision necessary. It *is* varargs. It's received as an array of the type specified. You have to log it accordingly. At present you're logging it as `long[].toString().`